# DirectLine REST API changed (channelData field is not a string )

Tags: botframework

According to the DirectLine API documentation, the channelData field in the message object should be a string:
http://docs.botframework.com/sdkreference/restapi-directline/#!/Conversations/Conversations_GetMessages

It used to be the case but since yesterday the API returns a JSON object.

Is this API versioned? It would help to be able to specify a version in the headers or the URL to avoid this kind of breaking change in the future.

Comment: This actually is a doc bug. The API didn't work in most cases before and the fact that it was spitting out a string prior to this change is a surprise to me. Sorry for the break.

Answer (score 0):

No, the API is not versioned, but we will add this so you can control it.

Comment: The DirectLine 1.0.1 NuGet Package throws a "Unable to deserialize the response." exception because it expects a string and not a JSON object for the ChannelData field. When can we expect an updated version?